# Execution keeps timing out with this is 'do while' loop

Tags: java, do-while

I try to run this on the IDE and it just won't run.
Only inputting the number zero will run it.
Is it unable to leave the loop?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int number = scanner.nextInt();
       do {
            switch(number) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Language selection");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Customer support");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Check account balance");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Check loan balance");
                    break;
           } 
       }
       while(number != 0);
       System.out.println("Exit");
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do, but you need to update the "number" variable and maybe your while condition, because the code you show here, doesn't update the variable, so the while condition "number != 0" will keep true forever.

Comment: `number` is initialized to 1, and never changes, so it's an endless loop.  Perhaps you need to use `scanner` to get a value and update `number`?

Comment: Sorry the number one in there was a typo. I input different numbers using scanner

Comment: You need to split the line `int number = scanner.nextInt();` into  `int number;` before the while loop and then perform `number = scanner.nextInt();` within the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Two changes: Move the `scanner.nextInt()` line inside `do` and change the `while` condition from `number != 0` to `number < 1 || number > 4`:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        do {
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            switch(number) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Language selection");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Customer support");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Check account balance");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Check loan balance");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while(number < 1 || number > 4);
        System.out.println("Exit");
```

Comment: I feel like using labels are unnecessary here and not the best practice.  His `while` condition of `!= 0` already handles leaving the loop when the value is `0`, why does he need to `break` out of the loop from inside the `switch`?  If he wants your functionality, the loop condition should change.

Comment: Yes @Nexevis you are right. I misunderstood your problem initially and have edited my answer above.